# X11 forwarding fails without an error message

Tags: linux, ssh, x11-forwarding

I would like to ssh to a docker image with X11 forwarding.

When I connect using `SSH -X -v` and execute `xclock`, it seems like the application runs (it does not terminates), but no window is opened.

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` includes

```
X11Forwarding yes                                                                                                           
X11UseLocalhost no  
X11DisplayOffset 10                                                                                                         
AllowAgentForwarding yes
```

`xauth` is installed on docker image.

No error is reported after the print of

```
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
```

The result of `echo $DISPLAY` is `<<HOSTNAME>>:11.0`

I also tried `ssh -Y` instead of `-X` with no luck

Comment: Was using sequence number 11 (and not 10) intentional?  I think that SSH uses that number to map a display to a port.. I have to wonder if it simply doesn't know where to export the display to.

Comment: I think it happens because I tried to connect twice. On the first attempt the display number was 10.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?